# Entity model - Should I make an instance using context.Project.Create() or using the new keyword

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hi and thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

I want to make an instance of an entity (named Project) defined and created with entity framework.. Do i do that using `context.Projects.Create()` or `Project p = new Project():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always create it using new then add it to the context later (Possibly through a repository or service layer)

Creating it through context creates a requirement on the context and doesn't look as good.